# How to add Javascript projects to IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm forced to use the **IntelliJ community edition** and want to edit a **Javascript project**.  My IntelliJ project is created in a separate directory away from my source.

```
/dir1/IntelliJProjects/ThisIsMyIntelliJProjectDirectory/.idea
```

The structure of my project is currently:

```
maven-proj1 (pom is at /dir1/maven-proj1/trunk/pom.xml)
maven-proj2 (pom is at /dir1/maven-proj2/trunk/pom.xml)
maven-proj3 (pom is at /dir1/maven-proj3-using-git/pom.xml)
```

Some of the code being used is maintained in subversion (svn) and other code is in git.  The above maven (java) projects were imported using the supported "Import Module" when the Project Stucture Dialog is shown which allows you to specify a maven pom.xml file.

But how can I add

```
/dir1/javascript-proj1
```

to my existing project.

Below are the work arounds I'm aware of.

(1) Create a project and use /dir1 as the project base directory then everything under it is available.

```
Cons: 
#1: When searching I find matches in the SVN branches and tags directory.  
#2: Navigating is deeper to get past the maven-proj1/trunk directory.
#3: Probably others, but bottom line is I've tried this and don't like it.
```

(2) Create a fake pom.xml file and make IntelliJ think this directory is a maven-project.

```
This is the route I'm likely to pursue.
Cons:
#1 I must create some otherwise unnecessary files in my Javascript project.
```

(3) Use the Ultimate version of IntelliJ.  Not an option for me in this case.

If anyone knows of other solutions please let me know.  If you believe one of my above work arounds is the best way to do this, let me know that as well, and I'll accept that as answer (when it's clear there is no better alternative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a pom.xml file (something like this):

```
<project>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-name</name>
    <description>Fake POM so Javascript can be loaded into IntelliJ</description>
</project>
```

I could then add this directory as a "module" by selecting, Project Structure, clicking on the Plus-sign, and navigating to the pom.xml file I created.

I also marked the node_modules directory as "excluded" (but not sure this is important).

I suspected I had the answer, but want to thank the people who viewed and considered answering my question.